# how to get list of uploaded files by ajaxfileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i'm using ajaxfileupload in my asp.net project
i to get list of uploaded files and save them in database
but i don't know how i can get which files are uploading when i press on upload button

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete1(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = MapPath("~/images/") + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);

        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
     }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Try to get all the uploaded file names using ajaxfileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430672/try-to-get-all-the-uploaded-file-names-using-ajaxfileupload)

Comment: no i saw this post it is not